# cost time meaning of java gc.log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

> 2017-08-15T00:02:07.653+0800: [GC2017-08-15T00:02:07.653+0800: [ParNew: 235967K->15723K(235968K), **0.0227136 secs**] 364848K->144604K(1022400K), 0.0227920 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
>
> 2017-08-15T00:02:12.540+0800: [Full GC2017-08-15T00:02:12.540+0800: [CMS: 128880K->87130K(786432K), **0.3387968 secs**] 162905K->87130K(1022400K), [CMS Perm : 70825K->70786K(524288K)], 0.3388920 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs]

---

What does the black secs mean?
Is it the time gc cost?
Does it equals to the pause of process caused by gc?
Does it mean the second GC event cause the process to suspend **0.3387968 secs**? Does not the process run concurrently possibly with any type Garbage Collector,e.g., CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-garbage-collection-log) article, which breaks down the anatomy of the gc.log file.

In summary, yes, the highlighted portions of your log file refer to the time taken to complete each of those GC events.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In your illustration,"GC took 3.43 seconds to complete", Does it mean this GC event cause the process to suspend  3.43 seconds? Does not the process run concurrently possibly with any type Garbage Collector,e.g., CMS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230165/is-concurrent-mark-sweep-cms-a-stop-the-world-event